# Computing isogenous curves

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be elliptic curves defined over a field $\mathbb{K}$. An isogeny is a finite morphism
$$\varphi:E_1\to E_2$$
such that $\varphi(\mathcal{O})=\mathcal{O}$. It is possible to show that an isogeny induces a morphisms of the groups of $E_1$ and $E_2$. It is clear that isogeny is an equivalence relation. Furthermore, following Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* exercise 4.9.b, for a fixed elliptic curve $E$, the set elliptic curves of isogenous to $E$ is countable.

> We are looking for a way to compute explicitly this set of isogenous curves for a fixed curve $E$. Our ultimate goal would be to give a set of curves $\lbrace E_i\rbrace_{i\in I}$ such that if $\varphi: E\to E'$ is an isogeny, then there exists $i\in I$ with $E_i\simeq E'$, each $E_i$ being expressed explicitely in the Weirstrass form (assuming $\mathrm{car}(\mathbb{K})\neq 2,3$).

Many theorems & propositions in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* suggest a classification using subgroups of the fixed curve $E$. For example, proposition 4.12 tells us: "*For an elliptic curve $E$ and $\Phi$ a finite subgroup of $E$, there is a unique elliptic curve $E'$ and a separable isogeny $\varphi:E\to E'$ such that $\ker \varphi=\Phi$.*" This approach did not show much progress yet unfortunatly.

I hope you find this question as interesting as I do. Any progress on the question, as tiny as it may seem, is more than welcome. If anything is unclear, please let me know.

---

**Edit**: Thanks to [@Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) for pointing out this trivial case. Using Silverman's proposition cited above, if we have $\Phi=E[n]$, then the curve and the isogeny is $[n]:E\to E$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your high lighted question? Compute explicitly a set means what exactly?

Comment: A thing to keep in mind is that if $\Phi$ is the full $n$-torsion subgroup of $E$, then $E'\simeq E$ and the isogeny is just to multiple points by $n$.

Comment: @Mohan I edited the question and clarified the goal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you give a reference for this statement and/or a proof?

Comment: $[n]:E\to E$ is a finite morphism such that the point at infinity is mapped to itself. Its kernel is $E[n]$. QED. If $n1_K=0_K$ then there are issues with separability.

Comment: Wow that was trivial! Thank you for your comment. This leaves the classification regarding other cases. I will edit my post.

Comment: Alexis, I have a vague recollection of having seen somebody claim that the method of constructing $E/\Phi$ that I used [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1535852/11619) works quite generally. In other words, you get the function field $K(E/\Phi)$ as the subfield of $K(E)$ generated by $P\mapsto \sum_{Q\in\Phi}x(P+Q)$ and $P\mapsto \sum_{Q\in\Phi}y(P+Q)$. I was searching for it but couldn't find it. Unfortunately I'm not an expert.

Comment: Ok. I think that the result I recall is called Velu's formula. I'm not at all certain that it is exactly what I think it is, but the Google hits do suggest that it is a method for constructing the curve $E/\Phi$ given $E$ and $\Phi$. Do look it up!