# An example of elliptic curve which is isogenous but not isomorphism

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm looking for an example of elliptic curve which is isogenous but not isomorphism.

$[m]$ is typically map which is not isogeny which is not isomorphism.

For example, what is the image of multiplication by $2$ isogeny $[2]$ of $E:y^2＝x^3-x$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field an isogeny is always surjective, so the image is $E$. The same holds for all non-constant morphisms between projective curves actually.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1535852/11619) I try my hand at identifying/constructing the image of an isogeny with a prescribed kernel. If you mod out full $m$-torsion for any $m$ you always get back the original curve. I really wish somebody who actually understands elliptic curves would give a better answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you might try reading the Magma documentation for the intrinsic ```IsogenyFromKernel``` - I've always used this as a black box but it'd be interesting to know how it works in a non-naive way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Jyrki in the comments, any non-constant morphism $C_1 \to C_2$ between smooth projective curves is surjective on the $\bar{K}$-points. In particular since for any $m \geq 1$ the multiplication by $m$ endomorphism
$$[m] : E \to E$$
has image $E$. Since $m$ has degree $m^2$ such a morphism cannot be an isomorphism.

Such an isogeny is rather "trivial" in the sense that the kernel of $[m]$ is the whole of $E[m]$ which is not cyclic. Any (separable) isogeny between elliptic curves may be decomposed as $[m]$ and a cyclic isogeny (i.e., an isogeny with cyclic kernel).

However with your curve $E: y^2 = x^3 - x$ there is a rather well known $2$-isogeny between $E$ and $E': y^2 = x^3 + 4x$ given by $(x,y) \to (y^2/x^2, y(1-x^2)/x^2)$.

This is not an isomorphism since $(0,0)$ is a nontrivial element of its kernel.

Comment: Thanks. Next I will enjoy the exercise of verifying this. Particularly the fact that $(0,0)$ is mapped to the point at infinity. I'm fairly confident that I will manage. But I still expect to enjoy it :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if you want a real challenge figure out what the claim should be when $y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$ (i.e., a generic elliptic curve with a rational $2$-torsion point). The answer should be somewhere in Silverman Ch.III